# Can a Boolean flag be used instead of a semaphore?

Tags: semaphore

Semaphore does the job of signalling whether a resource is free or being used.Can we not replace the same with a boolean flag. How is a semaphore different from flag?

Comment: Thread safety and blocking.

Answer (score 3):

Semaphores count; one increments and decrements them — they tell you how many of a resource is available and allow you to wait for one. A Boolean does not count.

Thread-safe use of a Boolean would require some other synchronisation mechanism. The main risk is that code like this:

```
if(!flag) {
    flag = true;
    ...
```

... results in two threads simultaneously checking `flag` and proceeding before either has set it.

A fairly common assembly instruction is atomic test and set (or clear), which does the two things as a single atomic step. That's often used for basic synchronisation.